# MS outlook Addin how to prefill From, To, Bcc on new Mail Created? Which is the event which occurs when a new item is created

Tags: .net, events, outlook

I am developing an Outlook plug-in with which I want to prefill From, To or BCC fields when a new mail item is created. Can you point me to the event that I can use to do that and on which object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latch onto the [`Inspectors.NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx)to capture when new message items are opened. To determine if the message is in compose versus read mode check [`MailItem.Sent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sent.aspx). To prefill the fields, you can easily access the properties with [`Outlook.MailItem` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx).

This should be a good jump-start for you, but you really should read the [Outlook Object Model overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to better understand plugin integration.